# Browser cache on files you host

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, apache

I understand how to use version numbers and force the download of updated files on my own website but what can be done under this circumstance.....

I have some small scripts i've written for public use , and i have about 200 different websites who link my js file on their website. When i make an update to the file , i have to get them all to manually change the version number of the file so they and their users are re downloading the latest update.

Is there anything i can do on my server , the host , that can force the other sites to redownload latest version without anything manual on their end of things ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are 2 persistent problems in computing: Cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors.

If you want clients to get new versions of a file without changing the name of the file then you simply have to lower the `max-age` you set in the caching headers so that they check more frequently and get the new version in a reasonable period of time.

That's it. End of list.

You can somewhat mitigate the effects of the increased request load by also implementing an [`ETag` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/ETag) that the client will send back on subsequent requests and can be used to detect if the resource is unchanged and optionally serve a `304 Not modified` response.

However, depending on the cost of implementing and running ETag checks you might just want to re-serve the existing resource and be done with it.

Or use a CDN which should handle all the ETag nonsense for you.